# Create a combined list of objects in the same table using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application has groups and relationships between users.
Relationships are mutual, so in every group G, user A will have a label for user B and vice versa.

Here's the code for the Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", optional: true
```

On the Show User view (a.k.a. the "user profile" page), I'd like to create a table listing all the relationships, that would look like so.

```
| Group | User | Label for | Label from |
|-------|------|-----------|------------|
| Clowns| B    | "Bozo"    | "Ninny"    |
| Dogs  | C    | "Rex"     |            |
| Tools | B    | "Hammer"  |  "Wrench"  |
```

So, with some help from @Rohit Patel's answer, I've progressed to the following syntax.

```
Relationship.select(:id, :group_id, :user_id, :receiver_id, :label, :'b.label as label_received').joins("left join relationships as b on relationships.receiver_id = b.user_id and relationships.group_id = b.group_id").where("relationships.user_id = 1")
```

It gets me the rows I need, but not the extra fields from the objects in `b` and `groups`.

The SQL to represent this would be:

```
SELECT a.group_name, a.user_id, a.label, b.name 
FROM relationships AS a
LEFT JOIN
relationships AS b
ON a.user_id = b.receiver_id
WHERE a.user_id = "A"
```

I can't figure out how to do this with ActiveRecord.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Following should do:

```
Relationship.all(:select => "relationships.group_name, relationships.user_id, relationships.label, b.name",
         :joins     => "JOIN relationships AS b 
                              ON relationships.user_id = b.receiver_id",
         :conditions => ["relationships.user_id = 'A']
)
```

Let me know if it helps!